# Compile jpeg_read.c as mexmaci64 for MATLAB

Tags: macos, matlab, compilation, mex

I downloaded the jpeg_toolbox for MATLAB from [this site](https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/image-forensics/tree/master/matlab_toolbox/Util/jpegtbx_1.4), then downloaded the JPEG compiler tools from [here](http://www.ijg.org). I followed the instruction to configure the whole for Mac (UNIX*).

Now, I would need to compile the `jpeg_read.c` and `jpeg_write.c` contained into the first link for MATLAB, because the toolbox does not provide the mexmaci64 files. However when I try to:

```
mex jpeg_read.c
```

MATLAB returns the following error:

```
Error using mex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_jpeg_CreateDecompress", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_destroy_decompress", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_finish_decompress", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_read_coefficients", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_read_header", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_save_markers", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_std_error", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
  "_jpeg_stdio_src", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in jpeg_read.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I compile the program? Otherwise, does any of you have already got the mexmaci64 I would need?

Comment: You'll need to link against the library also. As the instructions tell you: `mex -I<IJGPATH> jpeg_read.c <LIBJPEG>`.

Comment: Yes, and there are supposed to be some libraries called libjpeg.a/libjpeg.lib, but I can only find extensions that the mex compiler does not recognise.

Comment: The instructions also say "build the libjpeg library using the make files and instructions contained in the IJG JPEG distribution." If you did that, you'll have a file called `libjpeg.a` or `libjpeg.dylib`. Add that file, including the full path, to the `mex` command as directed.

Comment: I did it, actually, but the only libjpeg files have extension `.la` `.map` `.pc` `.pc.in`. However, if I try to use mex with one of those, the compiler complains it does not recognise nor of those.

Comment: And there are no files at all with a `.a` or `.dylib` extension?

Comment: exactly, none of them.

Comment: Then it either didn't build or it put the libraries somewhere you are not looking. But MacOS comes with libjpeg, maybe? Try adding `-ljpeg` to the mex command, instead of the library file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
brew install libjpeg
```

I found the libraries in `/usr/local/lib` so on MATLAB I moved into the folder that contained the `.c` files that had to be compiled and I ran:

```
mex jpeg_read.c "/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a"
mex jpeg_write.c "/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a"
```